# Check if exists a certain key in Firebase Database

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm learning about Firebase and trying to implement Firebase Auth and Firebase Database in a system of users. 
I know how to use Firebase Authentication with Facebook but I want to add some attributes for each user (in Firebase Authentication we only have e-mail, uid, provider and profile image url).

My solution was to create a user registry: 
[image: Database image]

**Problem**

So what I want to do is just make a **push** only the first time the user sign in. This is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseReference myRef1;
DatabaseReference myRef;
private int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
private String urlI, uid, name, uide;
boolean check_rate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myRef1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    myRef = myRef1.child("Usuarios");
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    id();

    if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        uide = auth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid().toString();

        if (check_rate) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));
            finish();

        } else {
            Map mProfile = new HashMap();
            mProfile.put("name", auth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName().toString());
            mProfile.put("image", auth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl().toString());
            mProfile.put("uid", auth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid().toString());


            myRef.push().setValue(mProfile);
            startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    } else {

        // abre a tela de login
        startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                        .setProviders(
                                AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER)
                        .build(),
                RC_SIGN_IN);

    }
}

private void id() {
        myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Map data = (Map) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                //profile
                urlI = (String) (data.get("image"));
                name = (String) (data.get("name"));
                uid = (String) (data.get("uid"));
                check_rate = data.containsKey(uide);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                 Map data = (Map) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                 //profile
                 //Map mData = (HashMap) data.get("profile");
                 urlI = (String) (data.get("image"));
                 name = (String) (data.get("name"));
                 uid = (String) (data.get("uid"));
                 check_rate = data.containsKey(uide);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        });
    }
```

This does not work. Users upload every time they log in.
Help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to store a list of items, it is often best to store those items under their natural key.

For users that natural key is their `uid`. If you store users under their uid, you can directly determine the location to store the users:

```
Map mProfile = new HashMap();
mProfile.put("name", auth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName().toString());
mProfile.put("image", auth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl().toString());

myRef.child(auth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid().toString())
     .setValue(mProfile);
```

With this data structure, if you write the same user a second time, it will just end up writing to the same location again. So no data duplication can happen.